# cross-domain request working with jQuery but not with XMLHttpRequest()

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to retrieve JSON Data from the tumblr-API.

No problems when using jQuery

```
$.getJSON("http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/blog.com/posts?api_key=key&jsonp=?", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

But trying to get the data with an XMLHttpRequest, i get the

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
>   present on the requested resource. Origin 'localhost' is
>   therefore not allowed access.

error msg.

```
    var url = "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/blog.com/posts?api_key=key";
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.responseType = "json";
    xhr.onload = function () {
        console.log(xhr.response);
    };


xhr.send();
```

I really want to get the data without jQuery. So what does jQuery that i am not doing?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

By inserting a `?` in the URL, you are making jQuery issue a request using the JSONP technique instead of XMLHttpRequest.

To do this:

1. Assign your load handler function to a global variable. You should generate a unique name for this. (e.g. `var f_name = "jsonp" + ++unique_function_count; window[f_name] = function () { ... }`).
2. Replace the question mark in your URI with the function name
3. Create a script element `var script = document.createElement('script');`
4. Set the URI as the source of the script (`script.src = uri;`)
5. Load the script (`document.body.appendChild(script);`)